# Управление светодиодами через jeck разъем android смартфона

Tags: java, android

Уважаемые программисты, подскажите с чего начать?! Нужно через jeck разъем android смартфона управлять тремя внешними светодиодами (включать, выключать, мигать) через интерфейс самого смартфона. Реализуема ли эта затея и с чего начать писать приложение?!

Comment: jack - это "разьем". В смартфоне он совершенно не один. через какой именно?

Comment: @argamidon, прежде чем слать человека в Гугл, стоило бы уточнить, чего конкретно он желает добиться. В частности, какими именно светодиодами он хочет управлять. Вспышкой камеры? Тогда это (почти) по вашей ссылке. А если он хочет подключить какие-то внешние светодиоды к аудиоразъёму и управлять их свечением из приложения, это совсем другое дело. @Vladimir2610, уточните, что именно вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @metalurgus, откуда в телефоне несколько [jack](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E0%E7%FA%B8%EC_TRS)'ов?

Comment: @Zelta, А причем тут вообще ваш "Разъём TRS"? Как насчет USB Jack, micro-hdmi jack, и т. д.

Comment: @metalurgus, под «Jack» в 90% случаев подразумевают 3,5 мм TRS или аналогичный разъем. Ни разу не слышал «USB Jack, micro-hdmi jack, и т. д.», обычно говорят просто «USB, micro-hdmi, и т. д.». 

Кроме того, USB контроллер в телефоне вроде является ведомым... Куда еще теоретически можно подключать светодиоды?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос и речь о том, чтобы напрямую подключиться к аудиоразъему, то там проблема: он предназначен для проигрывания музыки, и, как я понимаю, руками установить там высокий уровень не получится. С другой стороны, можно подключить микроконтроллер, который будет «слушать» и анализировать выход. Тогда можно стримить звук, в котором закодированы сообщения для МК. Он их распознает и зажжет нужные светодиоды. Но если есть мк, проще делать через bluetooth.

Решение велосипедное, если уточните вопрос, может, что получше придумается.

Вообще, постучитесь еще на форум электронщиков, может, что подскажут.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что можно попробовать написать алгоритм для светодиодов на Java. Управлять, например, микроконтроллером c планшета. Имеется у меня микроконтроллер ATtiny 2313. Вот, честно говоря, интересно теперь реализовать простое мигание светодиодов со смартфона. Если получится что-либо интересное, обязательно сюда напишу и покажу. Собственно, конкретно по Вашему вопросу: затея очень даже реализуема и начинать нужно, конечно же, с основ программирования под микроконтроллеры. Для этой затеи лучше использовать С или Assembler, но если хотите попробовать Java, то загляните сюда: http://www.harbaum.org/till/nanovm/index.shtml